Bash Date only Returning Midnight
Just when I thought I understood Bash $(date) formatting. This simple script just returns 12:00 AM tried printf too, same. What am I missing?
The file $D5 is just a reference to an JSON element Date-Time. These lines represent the values respectfully
srx=$(cat "${D5}" | jq '.Data[0].sr')
#srx=$(date -d "$(cat '${D5}' | jq -r '.Data[0].sr')"
"+%s")
echo $srx

Returns
"Fri May 31 08:30:00 PM CDT 2024"
#1717340100

I pass this to:
srt=$(date -d "($srx)" +"%I:%M %p")
#srt=printf "$srx" %s "%(%I-%M)T/n"
echo $srt

Always returns: 12:00 AM

Whatever the content of $srx is, "($srx)" makes it an invalid date, and date -d '(…)' +"%I:%M %p" returns 12:00 AM.

Your text snippets aren't complete code (what is "+%s") on it's own line supposed to be?), you didn't provide sample input we could copy/paste to test with, and it's very difficult to figure out what it was you meant to write and what you wanted us to get from reading those text blocks. Are you trying to store the command cat "${D5}" | jq '.Data[0].sr' in a variable but you used "($srx)" instead of "$(srx)" to execute it? If so - don't do that, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050. Please provide a [mcve] wo we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do.

We don't know what's in your D5 file so we can't test this ourselves.

If cat "${D5}" | jq '.Data[0].sr' returns "Fri May 31 08:30:00 PM CDT 2024", then use the -r flag to decode JSON (i.e. to not contain the quoting).
Also, date -d "($srx)" +"%I:%M %p" puts parens around the date, which invalidates it (resulting in the result of 12:00 AM). Remove the parens.
srx="$(jq -r '.Data[0].sr' "${D5}")"
#         ^^------------------------------- add the -r flag

srt="$(date -d "$srx" +"%I:%M %p")"
#              ^^--^^-------------------- remove the parens

echo "$srt"


Te query line above with the -r is the one that returns Epoch Time. Both  return variables act the same when passed to $srt with or without quotes. Removing the parenthesis, gave a command line error.

If srx="$(…)" will store a Unix timestamp, use srt="$(date -d "@$srx" +"%I:%M %p")" instead (note the added @)
